# Visual Studio 2008: Keeping vertical space between tags when code formatting HTML

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

Quite new to Visual Studio, more of a PHP/Eclipse person.

I prefer to have lots of white space in my markup - it makes it easier to edit, I find.

However, when I format the markup with CTRL K CTRL D, VS2008 strips out all vertical whitespace (ie, newlines) between my tags.

Is there a setting to prevent this and only indent my markup?

I have not been able to find anything online that seems to address this, neither is there a previous question that I could find.

Thanks in advance,

G

Comment: Thanks for having a look at this - you're right it is possible but the way they've done it is totally barking...

Comment: I removed my comment already because my test in HTML was, by accident, on code in a javascript tag, for which the HTML formatter does not remove newlines. After doing it right, it removed newlines in HTML for me too. Anyway, nice job of finding it yourself :).

Comment: The credit goes to guy in my office a few desks across from me. It's often the way though that as soon as you ask something publicly, the answer comes along from some unexpected quarter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer: the settings for empty lines before and after HTML tags are, infuriatingly, *tag-specific*.  So I've had to set it in several places.

You don't quite have to do it for each particular tag, though, there are four kinds you have to set it for.

For your information, Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> HTML -> Format -> Tag Specific Options -> Default Settings and then the four types are listed under there.  Select your value from the 'Line breaks' dropdown and click OK when done.  The CTRL K, CTRL D will add lots of vertical whitespace as desired.

Thanks if you've been looking at this, and I hope this helps others.

G